# Javascript change target element of keydown / keypress event

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events

I have a div that picking up a keydown event, once fired I would like to change focus to an input field for the user to enter text. The input field is hidden until keydown.

I would like to somehow prevent the default keydown event, change the event target to the input element, then fire it again inserting the typed value into input.

Is there a way to change the keydown event element before having it fire?

---

The other way would be to interpret the initial keystroke and enter that as a value for the input element then focus for the remaining input. Which is a little messier but may be necessary.

---

https://jsfiddle.net/fr5xrsyd/4/

```js
$('.focus').keydown(function(e){
 $('input').addClass('keydown');
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target = $('input')[0];
  //fire event after target changed
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.focus {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5em;
  z-index:1
}

.focus:focus {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

input.keydown {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="focus" tabIndex="-1">
    Click me and type a value.
  </div>
  <input placeholder="typed value should appear here"/>
</div>
```

Comment: *"Is there a way to change the keydown event element before having it fire?"* - You say you are trying to do this in response to the same keydown event you want to change, so at that point the event has already happened. Incidentally, why are you making it impossible for keyboard-only users to use your page?

Comment: So the only way would be to interpret the initial keystroke, and enter that as a value for the input element, then focus the input for the remaining keystrokes?

Comment: @RyanKing try with `$('input').focus()`

Comment: Does the trick!

Answer (score 0):

`$('input').focus()` does the trick as per prasad's comment above.

```js
$('.focus').keydown(function(e){
 $('input').addClass('keydown');
  $('input').focus();
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.focus {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5em;
  z-index:1
}

.focus:focus {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

input.keydown {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="focus" tabIndex="-1">
    Click me and type a value.
  </div>
  <input placeholder="typed value should appear here"/>
</div>
```